# Why does NavigationLink make my app crash when there are no errors?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am making a simple notes app.  When I press a new note I want a text editor to appear for that note. I have had trouble making this run.  I finally managed to build the app without errors but it crashes so clearly I didn't solve anything. I know I must have made a logic error somewhere, but I still don't understand why the app builds but crashes when I press a note.

I think the problem has to do with my NavigationLink, more specifically the destination of NoteEditor. Here is my content view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Note.name, ascending: true)])
    var notes: FetchedResults<Note>
    
    @State private var NotesIds: Set<Note.ID> = []
    
    private var selectedNote: Note?{
        guard let NoteId = NotesIds.first,
              let selectedNote = notes.filter ({$0.id == selectedNoteId}).first else{
                  return nil
              }
        return selectedNote
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(notes, selection: $NotesIds){ note in
                NavigationLink(note.name, destination: NoteEditor(note: Note())) //where I think problem is
            }
            if let note = selectedNote{
                Text(note.text)
            } else{
                Text("No note selected")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .onDeleteCommand(perform: deleteSelectedQuickNotes)
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction){
                Button(action: createQuickNote){
                    Label("Create new Note", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createNote(){
         createNote(name: "New note", text: "")
        
    }
    private func createNote(name: String, text: String) {
        withAnimation {
            let note = Note(context: viewContext)
            note.id = UUID()
            note.name = name
            note.text = text
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func deleteSelectedNotes(){
        let selectedNotes = notes.filter {NotesIds.contains($0.id)}
        deleteNotes(notes: selectedNotes)
        
    }
    
    private func deleteNotes(notes: [Note]){
        viewContext.perform{ notes.forEach(viewContext.delete)}
    }
    
}
```

Note Editor:

```
struct QuickNoteEditor: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var note: Note
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text:$note.text)
            .onReceive(note.publisher(for: \.text), perform: setName)
            .onReceive(
                note.publisher(for: \.text)
                    .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                    .removeDuplicates()
            ){ _ in
                try? PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
            }
            .navigationTitle(note.name)
    }
    
    func setName(from text: String){
        let text = text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if text.count > 0{
            note.name = String(text.prefix(20))
        } else {
            note.name = "New Note";
        }
    }
}
```

Persistence Controller (not sure if relevant)

```
final class PersistenceController{
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Notes")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("cannot load data \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func saveContext(backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil) throws{
        let context = backgroundContext ?? container.viewContext
        guard context.hasChanges else { return}
        try context.save()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoteEditor(note: Note())` should be `NoteEditor(note: note)`

Interesting technique trying to save in `onReceive` it might break if the context fails to save and gets in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Thank you! What would you recommend instead of onReceive?